# How to locate a reference .dll after I delete it from project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dll

I deleted a reference to `EntityFramework` and I don't know where I can find it on my computer.

`EntityFramework` is installed by NuGet and it's still on the project. But without the reference, it can't find `DbContext`.

The first solution is to uninstall and install after, but others reference need to have `EntityFramework`, so I don't want to uninstall it.

I need to find a way to add the reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it here :

```
YourProjectPath\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall the package rather than uninstalling and then installing it.

```
Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
```

From https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstalled it you also have to delete it from packages.config file, Then you can install it again.

Comment: I don't want to uninstall, but I found the answer. Thanks you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I find myself an other way to do it, so I write it here !

You just have to update to a previous version, and reference will automatically be recreate, so it's working :)